# In my rails 3 app, simple_captcha doesn't display image on production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, captcha

The simple_captcha works find on my dev machine but it doesn't on my shared hosting server(Dreamhost).

ImageMagick is installed and RMagick is ok there.
What could be wrong?

I checked the log and it doesn't show any error message.

```
Started GET "/simple_captcha/0245065ca02e2f4fadc22b3f08e1357ea74221f8?time=1304535698" for 99.122.173.225 at Wed May 04 12:01:38 -0700 2011
```

When I type the address(/simple_captcha/0245065ca02e2f4fadc22b3f08e1357ea74221f8?time=1304535698), it says that "the image cannot be displayed because it contains errors".

Any idea what's wrong?

Thanks.

Sam

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried commenting out the

```
config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile"
```

line?

Found here:
[Rails sends 0 byte files using send_file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724853/rails-sends-0-byte-files-using-send-file)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem in a server running Ubuntu 10.10 + Nginx + Passenger.

I found the solution in this thread: http://www.mail-archive.com/heroku@googlegroups.com/msg06836.html

simple_captcha uses send_file to send the image to the browser. So you need to enable XSendfile in your production environment. You can do that putting this line in your environments/production.rb:

```
config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile"
```

In case you're using nginx, you have to use X-Accel-Redirect instead. See http://wiki.nginx.org/XSendfile

```
config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Accel-Redirect"
```

Comment: I followed your instruction (apache version) and my problem is still there. Thanks anyway. I'll keep searching...